# Auto increment column .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, auto-increment

I have an C# .NET web application and I want to create an auto increment on an id. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but I keep getting errors because it doesn't increase.

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Samen de Zorg.dbo.BulletinItem'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost] 
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserID,Title,Description")] BulletinItem bulletinItem)
    {
        // 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.BulletinItem.Add(bulletinItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(bulletinItem);
    }
```

Model:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<BulletinReaction> BulletinReaction { get; set; }
```

Model in XML:

```
       <EntityType Name="BulletinItem">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="256" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Title" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Description" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
```

Model in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BulletinItem] 
(
    [Id]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserID]      NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Title]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_BulletinItem] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_BulletinItem_AspNetUsers] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([UserName])
);
```

Comment: What does the column look like in SQL? Does it have the identity specification?

Comment: What are you using to generate your db? Code First EF?

Comment: @jrummell I've added the sql model on your request

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes, I'm using code first.

Comment: Like @jrummell hinted, you need to make `[Id]` an identity column in your database.

Comment: If you have XML (edmx), you're not using code first ...

Comment: In MVC entity framework you don't use use as null field in id column any one column should be primary .

Comment: @sstan Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need your model in SQL to not only say NOT-NULL but also AUTO_INCREMENT just add a space inbetween.